# About infinite loop space and $\Omega$ spectrum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, stable-homotopy, classifying-spaces

Let $A$ is an topological abelian monoid. Also $\pi_0(A)$ is a group and $A$ has $CW$ structure.
$BA$ is a classifying space of the topological abelian monoid.

My purpose is to construct an infinite loop space structure on $A$ and as a result I can obtain $\Omega$ spectrum on the $A$ (and with help of Brown's theorem obtain a general cohomology theory from $A$). In what cases is it possible? Is it just true when topological abelian monoid is a topological abelian group? Can you explain these in more details, please?

My thoughts are the following: 1) As I understand $BA$ is also a topological abelian monoid if $A$ is the topological abelian monoid. It's known that classifying space of a strict monoidal category is a $E_{\infty}$ space. J. M. Boardman and R. M. Vogt gave a recognition principle saying that
group-like $E_{\infty}$-spaces are (up to homotopy) exactly the infinite loop spaces. And $BA$ is a $E_{\infty}$ space. And $BA$ is an infinite loop space as a result.

1. In the case of topological abelian monoid. It's known that for topological monoid with condition $\pi_0$ is a group the map $A \to \Omega BA$ is a weak equivalence. It will be a homotopy equivalence when $\Omega BA$ and $A$ are CW complexes. $\Omega BA$ is also infinite loop space since $BA$ is an infinite loop space. My question is the following: in what cases can I obtain an infinite loop space structure on $A$?
2. In the case when $A$ is a topological abelian group. It's known that $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega BA$. And as I understand I can obtain infinite loop space structure on $A$ and generalized cohomology theory from $A$. Is it truth or not? Can you explain this moment in more details?

Thank you!

Comment: As to 2, of course, an infinite loop space defines a generalized cohomology theory.  However, as A is abelian, it is just ordinary cohomology (with graded coefficients).  As to 1, you give the answer yourself, that is when $\pi _0$ is a group.

Comment: @user43326 thank you for your answer. Is it possible to obtain generalized cohomology theory for 1 case for topological abelian monoid $A$ without condition for $\Omega BA$ being CW complex? Is weak equivalence enough condition for it? Or just homotopy equivalences give us generalized cohomology theory?

Comment: By theorem of Milnor $\Omega BA$ has homotopy type of CW complex.  https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-02/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4.pdf

Comment: @user43326 Thank you for this link. Do you mean theorem 2 in this paper? I can't find information about loop space of classifying space in this paper. Perhaps I am inattentive. If you don't mind can you explain please in answer why $\Omega BA$ will be a $CW$ complex? Thank you very much

Comment: No, I mean Corollary 2 with $S^0$ as $C$, $BA$ as $A$.

Comment: @user43326 I don't understand why we need to consider $S^0$. Can you explain please in more details how can we obtain that $\Omega BA$ is homotopy equivalent to $A$ based on Milnor's theorem? Thank you

Comment: Sorry I meant $S^1$

Comment: If $A$ is CW, then so is $BA$, and thus $BA ^{S^1}$ by Milnor.

Comment: @user43326 Thank you for your answer!